# IE11 browser hangs on click of input type file

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to upload files to the server for which I am using a jQuery upload plugin.

The issue is that as soon as I click on the Browse button the Windows file dialog box will not be shown. Instead IE11 hangs. The screen unfreezes after sometime and the Windows file dialog will be shown. This issue occurs only in IE11, but Chrome works fine.

There are no errors shown in the console.

```
<input type="file" id ="uploadFile0"  class="fileuplaod">
```

I am also using the below jQuery plugins

- jQuery 1.8.x
- jQueryUI 1.8.x
- jQuery validate 1.9.x
- jQuery ui.widget.js 1.8.x

  Please help me!

Comment: Do you have access to another PC that you can test this on to confirm that the issue isn't with your PC?

Comment: A delay before showing the windows file dialog is normally caused by the OS struggling to communicate with at least one of the drives in the system, and as such is not a browser/JS issue. However this would occur in every program on the machine, not just IE11

Comment: Thanks Shahzad for the reply..and this issue ocurrs with other systems as well.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan..the issue is that entire windows freezes and i need to go to the Task manager to close the IE. However is there any way we check the logs for this since as you told it might be delay in communicating with drives and also this is reproducible in other systems as well?

Comment: do those other systems have the same network drives mapped, by any chance?

Comment: No, but all systems are connected to same Lan.

Comment: @coder12349 Just to confirm, when you try the same thing on another browser (Firefox/Chrome/..), it works fine?

Comment: yes tried with chrome and edge as well!

Comment: Also i have added the screenshot of the issue. Button color turns blue when it gets hanged but no windows pop-up is shown.

Comment: Can you try recreating it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)